# How to get logo of a page when parsing?

Tags: html, parsing

I am trying to create a general parser for sites and get relevant information. First thing I would like to be able to do is being able to know what is the logo of the site.

Usually the logo will be an image that will link back to the main page, and might content the word "logo" in its ID.

What would be a good strategy or standards that I could apply in order to find what is the logo of a page when parsing it?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a way to make this a generic process. There are no rules about what how the logo of a site will be displayed - so there is no single ID, class, tag or location you can look to. Likewise, images don't "link" to anything, an `<a>` link might contain an `<img>` tag, but thats about it.

Short of writing a long, *long* list of best guesses, there is no way to reliably parse an arbitrary HTML page and get a logo from it.